# Memcache Synchronization

Tags: magento, synchronization, memcached

I would like to know if any of you had, or may propose a solution to increase efficiency for online store based on Magento platform.

We currently use multifront architecture (front == each separate server) using load-balancing and two Memcache servers.

We're considering connection for each separate front an Memcache server, but at this point a problem arises with memcache synchronization, so that each store the same value.

Any advice appreciated :)

Comment: How do keep a single memcached instance in sync with the database? Also, are you running memcached on its own dedicated hardware?

Comment: Hi, we're running memcached on other server.
"How do keep a single memcached instance in sync with the database?" Could You extend your question ?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are running memcached on its own hardware, there is no benefit to giving each store its own memcached server.

Configure all front ends to use both memcached instances. This way, all front ends will go to the same memcached instance for a given key. Plus, you get automatic fail-over if one instance croaks, and you can scale up almost linearly as the demand for cache increases.

Comment: HI, thx for anwser.
All fronts are configured to use both instances of memcache, but we don't know why we have big latency for memcache set method...

Q: "If you are running memcached on its own hardware, there is no benefit to giving each store its own memcached server." Why there won't be any benefit ?

Comment: @Lrrr: Because then each memcached server would have to hold the entire key space, whereas by load-balancing the way you are now, each server only has to hold half of the key space. I don't know why set is slow. You might have to provide more context (data volumes, key and value sizes, measurements such as latency, what's happening when the problem occurs, perhaps some sample code).

Comment: yes, you're right, it's better the way it is now.
Ok, i will provide some context data as soon as i get in touch with my staff.

Answer (score 0):

One of the biggest improvements I've seen for more advanced setups like these is to use a PHP Opcode cache like Xcode. Since Magento uses many PHP files, the opcode cache will end up saving a lot of compilation between runs. Also make sure that all your caches are turned on and leveraged as much as possible. Enable flat catalog and flat product tables as well.

Comment: Hi, we're using APC, all caches (except Full Page Caching) are active and we have enabled flat's, so for now we're trying to reduce latency for get/set in Memcache.